# Wordpress get URL of a post from its attachment

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding an image from media in every single post that are created.
To get the attached image and url of that post, I am implementing this code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'numberposts' => 5,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => 'any', // any parent
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ( $attachments ) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    setup_postdata($attachment);
    $v =$attachment->ID;
    $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_url($v);
    $postlink = get_permalink($v);
}
```

The above code works fine for retrieving image url. My question is how do I pass post ID in get_permalink() to make sure that I get link of that post. I know that passing $v in get_permalink() is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a code spinet to print attachment posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_parent' => 'any', // any parent
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $post;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($post);
    echo '</pre>';
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

Its depending which ID you are looking for inside the loop

`$post-ID` : That return the post ID for attachment post.

`$post->post_parent` : It returns the current attachment post parent post ID.